# Set multi color for Textview text

Tags: java, android, fonts

How to set multi color for http://www.fontspace.com/beeline/alphagarden font?
Question updated
How to set multi color for TextView text in android using java or xml

Comment: The original question is no where related this question now

Comment: This question is the answer for previous question , now i can set mullti color for textview and set font as AlphaGarden . Problem solved

Comment: i am not able to delte the question

Comment: When i try to delete it showing "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center." Please help me to delete it

Comment: Yes you cannot delete , all you had to do was accept the below answer , not change question to completely a different one

Comment: yes , i update with old question

Comment: Its better now .

Comment: I wrote some library which act similar to it. https://github.com/ha-yi/MultiColorTextView

Comment: please write it as answer

Answer (score 0):

The website is showing colored fonts just for the display.

Here is the comment from link provided by you

> All fonts are really just the "outlines" of the letters. You can use a
>   program like Adobe Photoshop, Paintshop Pro, or Microsoft Paint and
>   color the letters by hand (that is what was done in the colored
>   illustration shown)